# Hola, tengo este nuevo error Warning: include(../../app/database/db.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, html, mysql

actualmente estoy obteniendo este error y la verdad no entiendo porque pasa si las direcciones están bien escritas y rectificadas, alguien me puede ayudar?.

ARCHIVO: index.php

```
<?php require("app/controllers/topics.php");?>
<?php require("app/controllers/db.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>My Website</title>
</head>
```

ARCHIVO: topics.php

```
<?php
include("../../app/database/db.php");

$table = 'categorias';

$id = '';
$name = '';
$description = '';

$categorias = selectAll($table);


if (isset($_POST['add-topic'])) {
    unset($_POST['add-topic']);
    $topic_id = create($table, $_POST);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Categoria creada correctamente';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $categoria = selectOne($table, ['id' => $id]);
    $id = $categoria['id'];
    $name = $categoria['name'];
    $description = $categoria['description'];
}

if (isset($_GET['del_id'])){
    $id = $_GET['del_id'];    
    $count = delete($table, $id);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Categoria eliminada correctamente';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['update-topic'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    unset($_POST['update-topic'], $_POST['id']);
    $topic_id = update($table, $id, $_POST);
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Categoria actualizada correctamente';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: ../../admin/topics/index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

ERROR: Warning: include(../../app/controllers/topics.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 1

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../app/controllers/topics.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 1

Warning: include(../../app/controllers/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../app/controllers/db.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line

Comment: El error indica que no está encontrando el archivo. Los signos: `../../` indican  **retroceder dos directorios en el árbol de directorios desde el directorio actual**, luego, en la ruta que esté dos directorios hacia atrás, debe haber un directorio `app` otro directorio `database` y en él el archivo `db.php`  Muestra una captura de tu árbol de directorios abierto donde está `db.php`. Deberías usar constantes de rutas para evitar este tipo de errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano Oh, gracias no sabia eso y logre solucionarlo gracias a ti!.